# Did the Romans drop the x from "maxilla"?

Tags: pronunciation

C.M. Weimer quotes Cicero's [*Orator,* 153](https://www.loebclassics.com/view/marcus_tullius_cicero-orator/1939/pb_LCL342.427.xml), in [this answer](https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/490/118):

> How was the name of your ancestor changed from Axilla to Ala except from a desire to avoid a harsh-sounding letter? The same letter is removed by refined Latin speech from ***maxillae***, *taxilli*, *vexillum* and *pauxillum*.

This comes to me as quite a surprise. I had understood that *maxilla* is a diminutive form of *māla*; see, for example, [etymonline](http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=maxilla). Wouldn't dropping the *x* undo the diminutive? If the Romans dropped the *x*, what would the result be? *Māilla?* *Māla?* Wouldn't this cause confusion? Aren't there already too many homonyms clashing over *[māla](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mala#Latin)?*

Comment: It seems that the original form of at least some of these words did have "x," which was dropped before a consonant but not before the diminutive suffix *-ill-* which started with a vowel. So "axla" etc. https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ala#Latin But the x was dropped in the normal word, similar to how *iumentum* comes from  [Old Latin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_Latin#Consonants) *jouxmentom*. I would guess this is the case for *māla* as well (i.e. it was earlier *maxla*). Posting this as a comment because it is just a guess.

Answer (score 9):

I think sumelic is correct, though both De Vaan and Etymonline disagree. If I may quote Lewis and Short:

> maxilla , ae, f. dim. of a ground-form magsula (whence māla; root mag of μάσσω, to knead; μαγεύς. baker, etc.; cf. axilla, āla, from ago)

This makes sense, too, because *-xilla* is not a proper diminutive suffux. So here, the root is *mag-* with a sibilant for the ending. Making *that* diminutive gives us *magsula* or with a more modern orthography *maxilla* (cf. older Latin *optumus* and standard *optimus*).

De Vaan derives it back to *smaksla-* (cf. OIr. *smech* 'chin', Hit. *zamakur* 'beard', Lith. *smakras*, 'chin', etc.). However, he doesn't really account for the loss of the gutteral in *māla*; instead, he derives both from *PIE*.

> *Māla* reflects **smaks(V)la*, whereas *maxilla* can be from **smakslela*, or has the productive suffix *-illa*.

However, if we were to use other Latin words for analogy, as Lewis and Short points out, āla is impossible to derive from *ag-*, and it makes more sense to go this way:

ag- > axis > axilla > āla

It should be noted that *x* easily slips away from words, as it turned into /h/ in Spanish, *s* or *ss* in French, and *s*, *ss*, or *sci* in Italian.

Comment: The same change occurs in all clusters of the form -Csl-, -Csn-, -Csm-: the first two consonants are lost with compensatory lengthening of the preceding vowel. Weiss *Hist. Gramm. Latin* 177-9 gives many examples.