# Why is "atque" preferred over "ac" before a vowel?

Tags: elision

Why is **atque** preferred before a vowel? Isn't the *-e* just asking to be elided there (in ordinary speech, not just poetry)? Why not just go with **ac**?

Answer (score 2):

The shorter *ac* is not the same thing as *atque* with elision.
The former is a short (light) syllable, the latter a long (heavy) one.
Latin seems to want to preserve syllable length in sound changes, so its importance is not limited to poetry.
So yes, the *-e* will be elided, but there still is a difference between *atqu'* and *ac*.

The original form is *atque* (*at+que*), and when words are changed, Latin has a tendency to preserve syllable length.
There is nothing wrong with *ac* per se, but there is something wrong with **turning** *atqu'* into *ac*, because such a change would turn a long syllable into a short one.
The reason is historical; it has to do with where the word comes from and how sounds can change in Latin.

For a concrete example, take Vergil's Aeneid I.464:

> *Sic ait atque animum pictura pascit inani*

The fourth syllable of the verse — the first of *atque* — is long because it is followed by a consonant cluster.
If you were to replace it with *ac*, the syllable count would be the same, but the fourth syllable would become short, invalidating the hexameter.
The single syllable of *ac* is short when followed by a vowel, and this is precisely the setting you asked about.
I chose an example in poetry so that the effect of syllable length is emphasized, although the effect is not limited to verse.

Of course this would be circumvented by pronouncing *ac* as *acc*, but that would probably be more confusing than using *atque* with elision, which makes pronunciation self-evident.
Remember that [elision is not specific to verse, but is also a feature of prose in classical Latin](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/489/79).

This doesn't explain why or how *atque* is shortened to *ac* before a consonant, but that wasn't your question.

Comment: Fac exemplum vel duo addas qui rationem illustret.

Comment: @BenKovitz Exemplum addidi. Facitne illud responsum clarius?

Comment: Non tamen intellego cur "ac" prae vocale vel "atque" ante consonante non convenit vel in locutione cotidiana vel in versu metrico. Cotidiane, quidni "Meus dominus ac erus frutex atque porcus est" dicatur? Versu, quidni "Sic ait, atque rationem campo pascit nudo" si hexametrum facit?

Comment: @BenKovitz To avoid confusion (mainly in my head), let me reply in English. The point is that the original form is *atque* (*at+que*), and when words are changed, Latin has a tendency to preserve syllable length. There is nothing wrong with *ac* per se, but there is something wrong with **turning** *atqu'* into *ac*. The way I see it, *atque* is the original, and the abbreviation *ac* is only permissible when it doesn't shorten a syllable. (I'll clarify this point.) I seem to be unable to scan your suggestion as a hexameter; the syllable lengths seem to be `– v v – v v v – – – – – – – –`.

Comment: Ahh, nunc video. Id quod conservatum est, non intellegeram. Forsitan clarius Latine ;) Re hexametro, "rationem" consonantalem "i" habet.

Comment: @BenKovitz Bene! Talis aspectus historicus parum patebat in versione prima. Quod ad hexametrum attinet, cum consonantali I aliter aptum est, sed metron paenultimum solet esse dactylus, non spondaeus. Metrice (haud grammatice) melius esset scribere *pascere* quam *pascit*.

Answer (score 0):

This question has been asked and answered before:

[What is the difference between "ac" (or "atque") and "et"?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/1371/what-is-the-difference-between-ac-or-atque-and-et)

To save you time, Allen's book on the subject is online at a url in the second of the answers given there.

Comment: I think I'm asking a different question (why the preference before a vowel, not what's the difference), but it does look like my answer might be on or near this page: https://archive.org/stream/doctrinacopularu00alle#page/n9/mode/2up